# How can I bend a a display object?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, 3d-engine

I want to make collage,

Example : http://www.as3.ro/p1_anim4.swf  (1.4 mb);

I want to bend images using as3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. Any solution to this problem will involve a lot of experimenation, and cleverness.

For the 3D aspect of the transformation, investigate Papervision.
For the 'bend' aspect of the transformation, investigate DisplacementMapFilters.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would use Papervision; with [as3mod](http://code.google.com/p/as3dmod/). "AS3Dmod is a library of modifiers for 3d objects." - with a bend function.