# Can Flash perform complex 'wrap' transformations?

Tags: flash, graphics, 3d, transformation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I bend a a display object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824848/how-can-i-bend-a-a-display-object)

Is it possible to use Flash to do more complex 3D transformations?

I already found out 3D rotations are possible. Additionally I also need some warp transformation in order to 'wrap' an image around a bottle.

[image: warped logo on mug]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The DisplacementMapFilter might be the thing you're looking for. It's quite complicated to use, but there are some tutorials like http://nodename.com/blog/2006/01/16/psyarks-displacementmapfilter-tutorial/ and http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/12/03/understanding-flash-displacement-map-filter/ that are helpful to understand how it works theoretically. Make your transformed image look real will be hard work, though...